# aspnet_membership issue

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2019

I really don't know how to explain this, but here I go...

**Stage**

In the company where I work there is an *Ubuntu 16.04* server with a *SQL Server 2019 database engine (15.0.4063.15)*. There are several databases.

One of these databases (let's call it BasePrincipal) stores products, customers and services. It also has several tables with the prefix *"aspnet_"* that store information on users, profiles, and applications. I don't know what this type of implementation is called. I understand that it is about authentication and authorization.

Another database (let's call it BaseSecondary) stores other information. But, it also has a table of users *(UsuarioRegionales)* with some basic permissions and also `UserId` and `Password` of each user.

There is also a website where users must identify themselves in order to access.

**The problem**

If a user tries to identify himself 5 times in an erroneous way, he is blocked. This is in the `aspnet_Membership` table, when the value of the `FailedPasswordAttemptCount` field reaches 5 the `IsLockedOut` field is marked with 1.

An internal application (web, intranet) offers the possibility of unblocking the user. It does this by executing stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[gnNoti_UsuariosUnblock]
    @UserId uniqueidentifier
ACE

    SETNOCOUNTOFF;
    UPDATE dbo.aspnet_Membership SET
        IsLockedOut = 0
        , FailedPasswordAttemptCount = 0
    WHERE UserId = @UserId
  
SET ANSI_NULLS OFF
GO
```

Now, every time a user is unlocked, in the SecondaryBase, *UsuarioRegionales* table, the `Password` field is updated with the value *'xxx'* and I don't know where this value comes from.
This happens immediately: the user is unlocked and the value of the password in the other table changes.

- There is no default value for RegionalUsers.Password
- There are no triggers on any of the tables.
- There are no jobs that refer to these tables.
- Other methods are not executed after or before the mentioned stored procedure.
- There are no relationships between the two tables that justify this behavior.
- There are no events related to the action.
- There are no scheduled tasks on the servers that call any script or program with reference to this.

**Question**

What I need to solve is why this value appears to change. I have been checking programs and databases for more than a month without finding a relationship.

If anyone has been through something like this or has an idea, it would be a great help.

Thank you very much.